# Why do low concentrations of $\rm H_2$ in $\rm He$ gas exhibit lower thermal conductivity than either?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, hydrogen, gas, thermal-conductivity

Thermal conductivity of He+H2 mixtures, as a function of molar concentration of H2, exhibit a minimum at around 14% H2. See Fig. 2 below from "[Thermal conductivity of the hydrogen-helium mixture](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00842864)".  What is the explanation for this dip?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the 1960's, it was [thought](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0508-3443/18/5/313/meta) that anomalous cross-relaxation was required to explain the minimum.  However, just a few weeks after you posted this question, a more convincing [partial answer](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.99.030102) was published in *Physical Review E*.  According to the paper, the observed minimum can be modeled accurately in the context of revised Enskog theory using a simple binary hard-sphere model.

I'm not sure if there is a good intuitive explanation for this behavior; the paper depends heavily on computational modeling.  If it's helpful, the important unusual feature of the hydrogen-helium system is that hydrogen molecules are much lighter than helium atoms (2 vs. 4 amu) but are physically larger.  The paper predicts that other systems with the same property, such as krypton/nitrogen, may exhibit similar behavior.